# How do I copy a file to tomcat webapp folder using maven?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat6

I want to copy a resource file from src/main/resources to `Cargo` `Tomcat` in /target/tomcat6x/container/webapps using `Maven`.

I tried using `maven-resources-plugin` but am not having any success.

I tried this:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <wait>false</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>
                            http://mirrors.enquira.co.uk/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.30/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.30.zip
                        </url>
                        <installDir>${installDir}</installDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <output>
                        ${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x.log
                    </output>
                    <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <copy>
                          <file>src/main/resources/datasource.properties</file>
                          <!--tofile>${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x/container/webapps/datasource.properties</tofile-->
                          <todir>${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x/container/webapps</todir>
                        </copy>
                    </files>
                    <home>
                        ${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x/container
                    </home>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8081</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>


            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deployer>
                            <deployables>
                                <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <pingURL>http://localhost:8081/charmweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/</pingURL>
                                    <pingTimeout>180000</pingTimeout> 
                                    <properties>
                                        <context>charmweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</context>
                                    </properties>
                                </deployable>
                            </deployables>
                        </deployer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

... but the file is not copying before the server starts and the application gets pinged.

Does anyone know how to use it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the maven-antrun-plugin for this and execute an ant copy task:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <copy file="src/main/resources/fileToCopy"
                        tofile="${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x/container/webapps/fileToCopy" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: thanks @K. Claszen since its gonna go with maven cargo, and if anything is in the directory of maven cargo, it deletes it. so better use maven cargo plugin and mention the phase. but im not sure how to.

Comment: hi , many thanks, at the end, i ended up using your solution and rather i am copying it to the temp cargo tomcat webapps. so no conflict. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

ok here is the answer.:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <wait>false</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>
                            http://mirrors.enquira.co.uk/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.30/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.30.zip
                        </url>
                        <installDir>${installDir}</installDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <output>
                        ${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x.log
                    </output>
                    <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <home>
                        ${project.build.directory}/tomcat6x/container
                    </home>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8081</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                    <files>
                        <copy>
                          <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/datasource.properties</file>
                          <todir>webapps</todir>
                          <configfile>true</configfile>
                          <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        </copy>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
```