# Maven war build copy-resources: tomcat7:run does not recognise copied resources

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a war project. A few static HTMLs need to be copied into the webapp folder before building war. To achieve this, added `maven-resources-plugin` `copy-resources` goal (`process-resources` phase). This is working fine as I can see the built war includes the copied files.

When I run this war using `mvn tomcat7:run` the path is not recognised (404).

However, when I deploy the war into a tomcat server, the path is accessible.

Any thoughts? Looks like tomcat7 plugin does not use the built war but accesses the files directly from src folder. Is this a bug or just how tomcat7 plugin works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the additionalClasspathDirs param? from https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

```
additionalClasspathDirs:
  Additional optional directories to add to the embedded tomcat classpath.

Type: java.util.List
Since: 2.0
Required: No
```

if that doesn't work you can use maven-antrun-plugin  see [how to copy a file to tomcat webapp folder using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885818/how-to-copy-a-file-to-tomcat-webapp-folder-using-maven)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I resolved this by copying the resources to the source folder prior to build. This works well.